# Using 'gsutil mv' without any exceptions shown

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I am using `gsutil` to move files, but this generates an exception if none of the files are moved.

This is the command I run:

```
gsutil -m mv gs://{url}/20200116* gs://{destional url}/data/rtbiq_data/
```

The exception I see:

> CommandException: No URLs matched: gs://{url}/20200116*
>   CommandException: 1 file/object could not be transferred.

I want it to just go through without any exception being thrown even if none of the files are moved. How can I do that?

Comment: Since this is a shell command ... can you not redirect the output of gsutil to /dev/null and be done with it?  If the command fails, it won't terminate the execution of any other subsequent commands.

Comment: It makes sense @Kolban

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't an official [`gsutil mv`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/mv#options) option to do that, but an one approach is to simply redirect the output of the command to `/dev/null`, essentially supressing `stderr`:

```
gsutil -m mv gs://{url}/20200116* gs://{destional url}/data/rtbiq_data/ 2> /dev/null
```